# RSPEC is finding my file but not my examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

So I put a "hello world" in my file to make sure I was getting to the file, and sure enough, it printed.  However, none of my examples are being run.  It says "no examples found".  Any ideas?

```
require 'rails_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  print "hello world"

  setup do
    @post = posts(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:posts)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create post" do
    assert_difference('Post.count') do
      post :create, post: { body: @post.body, title: @post.title }
    end

    assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
  end

  test "should show post" do
    get :show, id: @post
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @post
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update post" do
    patch :update, id: @post, post: { body: @post.body, title: @post.title }
    assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
  end

  test "should destroy post" do
    assert_difference('Post.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @post
    end

    assert_redirected_to posts_path
  end
end
```

If more code would help, let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, it's in a "test" folder, is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not rspec, that's testunit, you don't run it with rspec, you run it with `rake test`

Comment: Oh duh... Thanks.  So is this incorrect formatting for an rspec test?